# Adding new fonts to Oracle Reports and take effect without restart server

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Sometimes i need to add new fonts to use in reports, but **i can't restart** production server everytime, is there any way to add new fonts for the reports and take effect **without restart the server?**

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is not, but you may as well just do the exercise once.

On the Oracle Support site, there is a note 261879.1 which gives a script to add a suite of fonts to the Report server configuration in a single pass.  You could use this (or tailor it) to add all the fonts you anticipate to ever need.